# ColdFusion microservices without a framework

Tags: rest, coldfusion, microservices

I have been looking all over for some samples with CF microservices done with some REST APIs without a framework like coldspring.

Any help?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why don't you want to use a framework? Why reinvent the wheel? Have a look at [Taffy](http://taffy.io/).

Comment: REST functionality is integrated directly into Adobe ColdFusion 10 and later (and Lucee 4.5 and above). Compared to some other Adobe CF docs, the Adobe CF REST documentation is actually quite good. Here's a reference link to get started: http://www.adobe.com/devnet/coldfusion/articles/restful-web-services.html Meant to post this as a comment, but alas, not enough rep to comment yet.

Comment: @Miguel-F Its hard to integrate a framework with an existing application. I steer clear of all CF frameworks as I get no value from them.

Comment: @volumeone The OP never said they were integrating into an existing application.